# Nginx - Routing, Capabililties of with Node.js

Tags: node.js, nginx, cluster-computing

I am running a Node.js server which is now getting more load and I need to start getting this running on multiple cores, as Node.js is single threaded and can only run on one.

This is a simple solution given the Node.js Cluster module and tons of NPM packages for this very thing.

I have a problem in that I need browser sessions to retain the same Node.js worker after the first request. This is because I store authentication data, etc. in a single node worker process and do not want to open the can of worms of messaging between worker processes, etc. etc.

My browsers store a session id cookie once authenticated, and I want a system to re-route requests to their correct worker based on their session cookie.

Nginx looks promising, but I know nothing about it, and *while I will put the work into it*, I would like to know before I spend hours diving into it, if it is capable of routing to Node.js worker processes based on arbitrary data from the request header, such as a session cookie.

Is this doable? If I know it is, I'll get down and dirty figuring out Nginx, ground up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are storing your sessions in nodejs memory. You might want to store your sessions in redis instead. This way it is persisted outside of a single server, and can be accessed from multiple processes.

In addition to redis, you might also want to look into Amazon Elastic Beanstalk for managing your load-balancing. You can setup an nginx proxy to route your requests to multiple servers based on their load.

This link might be able to get you started http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs_express_elasticache.html

Comment: I have really wanted to use Redis, but I am running Windows Servers unfortunately, and they have to be totally production ready despite dumb administrators halfway across the planet.